# Product of Grobner bases and product of the ideals generated by said Grobner bases

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, groebner-basis

Suppose $G, G'$ are Grobner bases for the ideals $I, I' \subseteq F[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ respectively. Then is it the case that $GG'$ is a Grobner bases for the ideal $II'$?

My intuition on this is no, but I am unable to come up with a concrete counterexample.

My own attempt:I have done a bunch of scratchwork, a mess of polynomial multiplications and coefficients, but I don't think I have much to concretely show unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G = \{ x,y \}$ and $G' = \{ x,y+1 \}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ with the lexicographic monomial ordering.

The sets of generators $G$ and $G'$ are Groebner bases of $I=\langle G \rangle$ and $I' = \langle G' \rangle$ respectively.

The product set $G \cdot G' = \{ x^2, xy+x, xy, y^2+y \}$ is not a Groebner basis of the product ideal $I \cdot I'$.

Indeed, $x = (xy+x)-xy \in I \cdot I'$, but there exists no $g \in G \cdot G'$ with $LT(g) \mid LT(x) = x$.

Comment: Isn't G=G'={x} a similar but even simpler example?

Comment: @miracle173 $\{x^2\}$ is a Groebner basis of $\langle x^2 \rangle$.